# How do I test new Swift classes without launching the UI?

Tags: xcode, swift

I am migrating over from Java. I am trying to use the main.swift file to do basic little tests of new classes as I learn the language, and make sure the methods in them work.

My problem is that I can't get the UI to stop launching. I tried commenting out //@UIApplicationMain, and attempted to add code to the main.swift file to prevent UI launch. All failed. Any tips? This should be a pretty simple thing to do I'd think.

Tried this:
http://qualitycoding.org/app-delegate-for-tests/

Comment: P l a y g r o u n d

Comment: Agreed, playground is what you are looking for. But I just cannot stop smiling at the name "main.swift", what a typical Java code!

Comment: I cannot access anything from the playgrounds. Whenever I try to "import" my classes, it just says it can't find my stuff.

Comment: You have to add your classes to the `Sources` folder of the Playground.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I add the class.swift file to Sources, attempt to initialize an instance, and nothing. I don't understand why this is so difficult. I only came to stack overflow as a last resort anyway. Do people just not test their classes anymore. wtf?

Comment: Ok, I got this to work by adding public modifier to the class, and every function in it. This is really ridiculous, and likely to create more problems then it solves. Thanks for the help. I guess I'll just have to waste time with the overhead of starting the simulator every time i want to test the most basic thing. **shakes head**

Comment: Forget playgrounds, create a console app.

Comment: Sulthan, this is what I was going for, only I can't keep the UI from launching, which disrupts my flow.

Comment: @ctd Has your question been satisfied? Of so, please accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new Xcode workspace, and move your project into it. Then, add a playground to the workspace. You can import modules from your project into the playground, and use them there.

Answer (score 0):

With the project and playground in the same workspace, you must then drag files from the project (whatever 'MyClass.swift' you wish to test) into the "Sources" folder of the Playground.

Everything you wish to test must use the "public" modifier.

EX:

public class Insect{

public init(){
   ......
   }

}

Unfortunately, the changes you make to that class while fooling with it in the Playground will not carry over to the project, so just drag and drop the new one, then delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add unit tests to the project and create testing classes.

- Unit test addition to project

  - Upon project creation: simply check the box
    [image: New project with tests]
  - If project was not created with the Unit test target

    - Add the target on the project

    [image: Add target]
    [image]
- Unit test class
  [image]

Here's a [good tutorial](http://nshipster.com/xctestcase) on the XCTTests you can create